# Saving date time for all time zones in java

Tags: java, android

I have an application in which user creates questions and others can
see date time (when the question was created) with it. Now i get the
server date time and save it in db but the problem is app is used by
someone who live in a country with a 6-7 hour gap.
Well a small example would be that i live in some country and i create question at time 7:00pm but time in USA is 11am (just a guess). So user immediately retrieves question but for him question time should be 11am and not 7pm.  So how can i save date time so it would be same for all time zones . I m kinda confused
so i need a little help . I know it's related to UTC date time but can
someone elaborate this a bit more :) . Thank u

Comment: dates don't have timezones. only date representations have. You store the date on its own, and when you display it, you apply the timezone depending on the locale.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Store into your database the difference, measured in milliseconds, between the current time and the [epoch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_%28reference_date%29) of midnight, January 1, 1970 UTC. that you can get by calling `System.currentTimeMillis()`.

Once you have it you can provide the time in any [Time Zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_zone) that you want, here is a simple code snippet that shows the time in [all the time zones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) available on my machine.

This code uses the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework built into Java 8 and later. Much of this functionality has also been [back-ported to Java 6 & 7](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) and [to Android](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP).

```
long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochMilli(time);
ZoneId.getAvailableZoneIds().stream().forEach(id -> {
        ZoneId zId = ZoneId.of(id);
        LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.ofInstant(instant, zId);
        System.out.printf(
            "The current time in %s is %s%n",  
            zId, localDateTime.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME)
        );
    }
);
```

Here is the equivalent for older versions of Java:

```
long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTimeInMillis(time);
for (String id : TimeZone.getAvailableIDs()) {
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'");
    formatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone(id));
    System.out.printf(
        "The current time in %s is %s%n",  id, formatter.format(cal.getTime())
    );
}
```

**Response Update:**

As you want to keep the original `TimeZone`, you will also have to store the time zone Id into your database in the *pseudo standard* format GMT+/-mm:ss.

For this, first you need to get the delta compared to UTC time (in the code snippet below `tz` is my current TimeZone):

```
int offsetFromUTC = tz.getOffset(time);
```

Then from this you can convert this delta in milliseconds into the expected time zone id which can be done like this:

```
String timeZoneId = String.format(
    "GMT%+02d:%02d", offsetFromUTC / (60 * 60 * 1000), offsetFromUTC / (60 * 1000) % 60
);
```

The value of `timeZoneId` is the second value that you have to store into the database. With these two values you can display the time in any expected format, for example:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
// Here I use the time retrieved from the DB
cal.setTimeInMillis(time);
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'");
// Here I use the time zone id retrieved from the DB
TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getTimeZone(timeZoneId);
formatter.setTimeZone(tz);
System.out.printf("The current time in %s is %s%n",  id, formatter.format(cal.getTime()));
```

Comment: i cannot import both instant and zoneid classes which means i have to use a library? . But i don't want to use a library

Comment: it is part of Java 8, which version of Java do you use?

Comment: @SyedMuhammadOan I updated my answer for previous version of Java

Comment: Ok i understand what's going on in the code but i still don't understand , what time should i save in the database?
and how do i convert that time when i use my android app . That was my actual question .

Comment: your a supposed to store into your database the long returned by _System.currentTimeMillis()_

Comment: ok but how will i know which timezone to convert to in my app . I mean how do i judge the scenario by long

Comment: You mean that you only care about the timezone of the user that creates the question if he is in New York and I'm in London, I'm suppose to see the time display with the TZ of NY not with my local TZ which would be the TZ of London on this case, is it your need?

Comment: i have edited my question and included an example. I didn't understand what u meant in ur comment .

Comment: @SyedMuhammadOan check my response after _Response Update_

Comment: thank u :)
u have given me enough data to complete the task on my own so i'll try it

Comment: Good answer, except there is no reason here to use [`LocalDateTime`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html) as that purposely loses the time zone information and gains you nothing. You could just as well use [`ZonedDateTime`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) to retain the time zone info and still generate a string in any format you desire. Change this: `LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.ofInstant( instant , zId );` to this: `ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.ofInstant( instant , zId );`

Comment: @BasilBourque thx for the feedback, actually the question has been modified several times originally the timezone was not needed that is why I proposed that, then it was needed and Java 8 was not the target version so instead of removing, I simply appended new content to the answer. I should indeed rewrite the answer properly

Answer (score 3):

> So how can i save date time so it would be same for all time zones

You should use UTC to store your dates, so if someone is using your app in +1 timezone, you need to convert it to UTC first. Timezone should only be used to display the time to the users.

Comment: Or just store the full date + timezone; you can convert to any timezone at your whim. If you use Joda Time it's particularly easy

Comment: U mean i should save utc date in db and convert it in my android app?

Comment: Yes. Use timezone to just show time as "local" to the user. So if s/he change time zone because i.e. of traveling, you will still be showing correct time in the TZ s/he will then be